# Accessing deeper level of JSON with org.json in JAVA

Tags: java, json, org.json

The below is the JSON retrieved and I have tried a lot of possibilities in order to obtain the value for "status" , and "lat", "lng" in "geometry.location".

I am a newbie in JAVA and JSON, I have spent more than 8 hours ,sitting in front of the computer to try the different solutions but it just failed.. Please help me

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

It is not working to retrieve "status"

```
JSONObject status = result.getJSONObject("status");
```

It is not working to retrieve "Geometry" as well as "lat" and "lng" in it

```
JSONArray  array = result.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = array.getJSONObject(2);
}
```

Comment: Peel it like an onion, one layer at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work because `"status"` in your object is a String, not an object. `String status = result.getString("status");` should work. (I'm guessing you're getting a `ClassCastException`?)

The second bit fails because you're attempting to get the object at index 2 of `array`, but it only has one entry. Pretty sure you meant to put an `i` instead of the 2 in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is using JSON Path. In JSON Path, the expression to retrieve "status" in your example data is simply `.status`. Google provides a nice library for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/). You can test JSON Path [here](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/).

You can find many examples/tutorials on JSON Path by Googling it. One I found rather quickly that seems to be faily comprehensive is [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Comment: Any tutorial or guideline for me to implement JSON path as I know nothing about it

Answer (score 0):

getJSONObject() returns an object and not the value. Try getString("result") or some equivalent:)

Answer (score -2):

JSONObject is fine for processing simple json data structures e.g. when starting with Hello Worlds etc. However the json structure you are trying to process is very painful to parse with JSONObject. Please stop trying to use the wrong tool for the job. Switch to faster xml Jackson Json library. In the wasted 8 hours you have spent so far you could have a learnt how to use Jackson and be on your way to being a Json ninja.

Comment: once again SO downvote with no explanation. If you are going to take the time to downvote, please explain why. Whats wrong with encouraging someone to spend their time learning a new approach. Do SO answers have to spoon feed the solution line by line? just so that it can be copy and pasted. what does anyone learn from that?